# When authenticating with oAuth and youtube, always get error : invalid_grant on 2nd auth attempt, why?

Tags: youtube, google-api, gdata

As of yesterday, my application is able to authenticate with google (youtube) via oAuth 2.0 the first time no problem but the 2nd time (re-authentication, same app + same user), when I exchange the requestToken for an accessToken I get an error:

```
error : invalid_grant
```

I'm using:

```
grant_type = authorization_code
```

like they suggest.  What used to happen, before 2 days ago, was on re-authentication the web page would say 'you've already authenticated with this application before, would you like to grant it access again?'.  What has changed or what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem, I am trying to refresh the token [link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#offline)

Comment: In the mean time I've found a work-around.  You can pass a parameter 'approval_prompt=force' to the authorize url and it will _always_ prompt the user to authorized your app, even if they've authorized it in the past.   So they'll never get the 'you've already authorized this app before' page but apparently thats not working anymore anyway.  More information here: https://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#formingtheurl

Comment: We're also having this issue.

Comment: In my case, it was caused by me using the `user_code` instead of `device_code` in the polling POST request data. Because `user_code` is for the human to type into the consent screen on their browser, not for the polling requests...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to fix this (at least for us).  When redirecting to the accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth url, we had to add both approval_prompt=force and access_type=offline.  If one was missing, we got no refresh token.

This url documents all of the parameters, but says nothing about the refresh token:  http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html

Comment: Aw man thats brutal, I didn't notice no refresh_token was being given, I wonder what user's reactions will be to the 'offline' notice that they're agreeing to :p

Comment: So I came to this same 'brutal' conclusion, and am now trying to exchange the refresh_token.. for a new one `grant_type=refresh_token` However I still get the same error identified above.

Comment: So for my understanding...the only way around this is to keep asking users for permission each time they want to log into your app???

Comment: No, we don't have to ask the user for re-auth every time.  We save the refresh token on our server and use it to request a new access token behind the scenes.

Without the fix I described above, YouTube had stopped giving us a refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/oauth2-dev/invalid_grant/oauth2-dev/eaOa6THER0k/z4eO-taUFxgJ

The problem was that that the "code" parameter that you need to send needs to be encoded. It will work when you set the approval_prompt to force because the return code contains URL-safe characters. However, this is not the case for the return code upon a second authorization request.

For me this fixed it, I hope it does for you as well.

Comment: Nobody knows why Google APIs through invalid_grant error.  In my case, the code works just fine for most users but Google throws invalid_grant for some users.  Google APIs don't provide any better explanation.  I looked into Google documentation, no clear answer.